# Are non-regular languages decidable?

Tags: computability

Given a language L, I've shown that L is not regular. Can I conclude that it is not decidable or are there non-regular languages that are decidable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context-free languages are not regular but decidable; on the other hand recursively enumerable languages are not regular and only semi-decidable. So sadly only knowing about the non-regularity of a language does not help with determining its decidability.